# Android Studio Request App Permissions won't compile

Tags: android, compilation

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. When trying to compile Android studio code I get the following error:

> ';' expected

[Code Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAUtL.png) 
[error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f67yk.png)

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }


  }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider posting the whole file or at least the line where you're getting this error. Because right now I can't tell if there is a problem.

Comment: when i try to post whole file stackoverflow says It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.Can i post screenshot instead.

Comment: Your code isn't wrong. The compiler should tell you where you're missing the `;`. Add it there and it should work.

Comment: i have posted error code image for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method outside of `onCreate()` method bracket.

Like below,

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
 ....
 ....
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: it shows error: cannot find symbol variable MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS

Comment: error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)

Comment: i have posted another image for error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)

Comment: Add semicolumn after this line. `int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;`

Comment: it shows error: constant expression required for line 47 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:

Comment: I guessYou are too new to this.

Comment: Just add `final` ahead of `int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;`. Like `final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;`

Comment: thanx bro for your time